# Java BouncyCastle Cast6Engine (CAST-256) encrypting

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to implement a function that receives a string and returns the encoded values of the String in CAST-256. The following code is what i implement following the example on BoncyCastle official web page (http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html , point 4.1).

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.CAST6Engine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;


public class Test {

    static{
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public static final String UTF8 = "utf-8";
    public static final String KEY = "CLp4j13gADa9AmRsqsXGJ";

    public static byte[] encrypt(String inputString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CAST6Engine());
        byte[] key = KEY.getBytes(UTF8);
        byte[] input = inputString.getBytes(UTF8);
        cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(key));

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

        int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        try {
            cipher.doFinal(cipherText, outputLen);
        } catch (CryptoException ce) {
            System.err.println(ce);
           System.exit(1);
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final String toEncrypt = "hola";
        final String encrypted = new String(Base64.encode(test(toEncrypt)),UTF8);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
    }

}
```

But , when i run my code i get

`QUrYzMVlbx3OK6IKXWq1ng==`

and if you encode `hola` in CAST-256 with the same key ( try here if you want http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/) i should get

`w5nZSYEyA8HuPL5V0J29Yg==`.

What is happening? Why im getting a wront encrypted string?

I'm tired of find that on internet and didnt find a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bouncy Castle uses PKCS #7 padding by default, while PHP's mcrypt (and the web site you linked) uses zero padding by default. This causes the different ciphertexts.

Please note that the ECB mode used here is not secure for almost any use. Additionally, I hope the secret key you posted is not the real key, because now that it's not secret anymore, all this encryption is useless.

Comment: jeje yes! That key is fail! But how i can use mcrypt like PHP? I need get the same encryption of PHP because im implementing a cakePHP server in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but it does provide some pointers.

You need to do a little digging to ensure you are decrypting in exactly the same way as PHP's `mcrypt()`. You need to make sure your key generation, encoding/decoding and cipher algorithm match exactly.

**Keys**

```
"CLp4j13gADa9AmRsqsXGJ".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

is probably not the right way to create the key source bytes. The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) seem to indicate that `mcrypt()` pads the key and data with `\0` if it isn't the right size. Note that your method produces a 168 bit key, which is not a valid key size and I'm not sure what java is going to do about it.

**Algorithm**
Make sure the cipher mode and padding are the same. Does `mcrypt()` use ECB, CBC, something else?

**Encoding**
Ciphers work on bytes, not Strings. Make sure your conversion between the two is the same in java and PHP.

Here is a reference test for CAST6 using test vectors from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2612#page-10. Note the key, ciphertext and plaintext are hex encoded.

```
import java.security.Provider;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Cast6 {

    static final String KEY_ALGO = "CAST6";
    static final String CIPHER_ALGO = "CAST6/ECB/NOPADDING";
    
    static String keytext = "2342bb9efa38542c0af75647f29f615d";
    static String plaintext = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    static String ciphertext = "c842a08972b43d20836c91d1b7530f6b";
    
    static Provider bc = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("encrypting");
        String actual = encrypt();
        System.out.println("actual: " + actual);
        System.out.println("expect: " + ciphertext);

        System.out.println("decrypting");
        actual = decrypt();
        System.out.println("actual: " + actual);
        System.out.println("expect: " + plaintext);
    }

    static String encrypt() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGO, bc);
        
        byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(keytext.toCharArray());
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, KEY_ALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        
        byte[] input = Hex.decodeHex(plaintext.toCharArray());
        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(input);
        String actual = Hex.encodeHexString(output);
        return actual;
    }
    

    static String decrypt() throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGO, bc);
        
        byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(keytext.toCharArray());
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, KEY_ALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        
        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(ciphertext.toCharArray()));
        
        String actual = Hex.encodeHexString(output);
        return actual;  
    }

}
```

Comment: if you try to encrypt with that key and that plaintext in http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/ you dont get the same result. I need to get the same result as that page.

Comment: @JoseF - Yeah I know. That's why you need to dig into the PHP and figure out exactly what its doing. The above key/plaintext/ciphertext *are* correct, they are one of the test vectors designed to aid testing of cipher implementations. Note that to use a hex key, you probably want to do `$key = pack('H*', "2342bb9efa38542c0af75647f29f615d");` in PHP.